# Mapping Map to DTO object using Jackson Object Mapper

Tags: java, rest, jackson, objectmapper

In my controller I am getting a Map which I am mapping to my DTO object using Jackson Object Mapper. Now I have an added condition in my api which needs another value(viewType) to be sent in Map which is not a field in DTO. How do I manage to send viewType in map along with DTO fields without getting Error: Exception thrown -Unrecognized field "viewType"

Below is how I am mapping Map to DTO

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  RetrieveDTO retrieveDTO = mapper.convertValue(req, RetrieveDTO.class);
```

I tried following but still not working

```
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

I tried

```
mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
```

And it worked

Comment: You can set this answer as Accepted

Comment: I can't accept my own answer before two days, will set it accepted tomorrow